# Importing a PyQt-GUI that can save values into another script

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, module, pyqt

I created a GUI using QtDesigner, converted the .ui into a .py and created a wrapper for it. The GUI consists of 3 DoubleSpinBoxes, two check boxes, OK, Cancel and a few labels. The ui-file (called gyroidUI.py) is bit lengthy, so I'll omit it here. The wrapper looks like this:

```
# gyroidUI_module.py
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QDialog
from gyroidUI import Ui_Form


class AppWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        # Ui_Form.__init__(self)
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.show()
        self.ui.OKButton.clicked.connect(self.OKButton_click)
        self.ui.CancelButton.clicked.connect(self.CancelButton_click)

    def OKButton_click(self):
        fill_ratio = self.ui.fill_ratio_box.value()
        contour_value = self.ui.contour_value_box.value()
        contours = self.ui.contours_box.value()

        use_contour_value = False
        if self.ui.check_contour_value.checkState() != 0:
            use_contour_value = True

        closed_surface = False
        if self.ui.check_closed_surface.checkState() != 0:
            closed_surface = True

        self.accept()
        print(fill_ratio, contour_value, contours, use_contour_value, closed_surface)
        return fill_ratio, contour_value, contours, use_contour_value, closed_surface

    def CancelButton_click(self):
        self.reject()
        raise InterruptedError("Program was cancelled by the user.")
        sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = AppWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In itself the wrapper works just fine. When I execute the file the GUI pops up, I can set 3 values and click the two check boxes. OK and Cancel also seem to work fine.

My question: How do I go about importing this into another script, where I then want the dialogue to saves the variables `fill_ratio, contour_value, contours, use_contour_value, closed_surface` with the corresponding values?

I tried

```
import gyroidUI_module

app = gyroidUI_module.AppWindow()
app.show()
# here comes the rest of my program where I want to use the GUI input values
```

but the window only pops up for a second, closes and the program finishes without executing the rest of my script. This is the important part: I want things to happen after the GUI (some `mayavi` and `vtk` related things)!

Thanks for any help on this!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like I found my answer:

```
app = gyroidUI_module.AppWindow()
app.show()

result = app.exec_()
if result == 1:
    fill_ratio = app.ui.fill_ratio_box.value()
    contour_value = app.ui.contour_value_box.value()
    contours = int(app.ui.contours_box.value())

    if app.ui.check_contour_value.checkState() != 0:
        use_contour_value = True
    else:
        use_contour_value = False

    if app.ui.check_closed_surface.checkState() != 0:
        closed_surface = True
    else:
        closed_surface = False
```

I am not exactly sure *why* it does what it does, but at least my code works now. Any explanations on why I need to check the value of `result` in the if-clause?